# R Building a function with a condition as variable

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I have a data.frame consisting of two columns, time and value. Let's say:

```
> s
>          time      value
>1  -1.40325749 -0.5282231
>2  -0.32640410 -1.8719568
>3  -0.26288196 -0.9861694
>4  -0.19906006 -0.8487832
>5  -0.18720951 -0.2248195
>6  -0.14219086  0.3387807
>7  -0.05981503  1.3872106
>8   0.37187516  2.0057095
>9   0.42432858  2.6805815
>10  1.19915563  1.9988563
```

I want to build a function which will filter this data, according to the specific condition. Here is my code:

```
> select<-function(object,cond)
 {    
     subset(object,eval(deparse(substitute(cond))))
 }
```

If I use now my new function as follows:

```
>select(s,value<0)
```

I would like to see only rows, where value is < 0. E.g.

```
> s
>          time      value
>1  -1.40325749 -0.5282231
>2  -0.32640410 -1.8719568
>3  -0.26288196 -0.9861694
>4  -0.19906006 -0.8487832
>5  -0.18720951 -0.2248195
```

However, after running this code, I have an error, that subset must be logical. I tried everything I know about to make the "value<0" visible as expression for R. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
Error in subset.data.frame(object, eval(deparse(substitute(cond)))) : 
'subset' must be logical
```

Regards
Michal

Comment: why not just use `subset(s, value<0)` instead of building a function that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these:

```
select <- subset

select <- function(...) subset(...)

select <- function(data, cond) eval.parent(substitute(subset(data, cond)))

select <- function(data, cond) {
  mc <- match.call()
  mc[[1L]] <- quote(subset)
  m <- match(c("data", "cond"), names(mc), 0L)
  names(mc)[m] <- c("x", "subset")
  eval.parent(mc)
}
```

and then using the builtin BOD data.frame

```
select(BOD, Time > 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also like `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
s <- s %>%
     filter(value < 0)
```

to filter rows by condition